# On the integral $\ I = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} \cos(cx)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The given integral is well known and has a closed form:

$$\ I = \int e^{ax}\cos(bx) dx$$

I was interested in computing the value of integrals of the form:

$$\ I = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} \cos(cx) dx$$

Where a,b,c are strictly positive.

I proceeded by defining

$$\ C(a,b,c) = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} \cos(cx) dx$$

and

$$\ S(a,b,c) = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} \sin(cx) dx$$

Then,

$$\ C(a,b,c) + iS(a,b,c) = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} e^{icx} dx = \int_0^{\infty}x^ae^{-(b-ic)x}dx$$

Using integration by parts,

$$\ C(a,b,c) + iS(a,b,c) = x^a \frac{-e^{-(b-ci)x}}{(b-ci)}\big |_{\ 0}^{\infty} + \frac{a}{(b-ci)} \cdot \int_0^{\infty}x^{a-1} \cdot e^{-(b-ic)x}dx$$

$$\ C(a,b,c) + iS(a,b,c) = 0 + \frac{a(b+ic)}{b^2+c^2} \cdot  (C(a-1,b,c) + iS(a-1,b,c))$$

I'm getting two recursion formulae if I simplify and equate the real and imaginary parts. If I write the recursion formulae in matrix format, it reminds me of vector rotation.

Can anyone suggest a good way to proceed further, or a better approach? I have no idea on how to extract $\ C(a,b,c)$ and $\ S(a,b,c)$ individually from the given recursive formulae.

Comment: You can calculate the values for $a=0$ directly and then use the recursion formula to get the result for arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integral is connected to the $\Gamma$-function which is a generalization of the factorial. It is defined as
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t}\text{ d}t, \ \qquad \Re(z) > 0\,. $$
The factorial $n!$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is then given by $n!= \Gamma(n+1)$.

Your integral can be written as
$$ I = \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-bx} \cos(cx) dx =\Re \int_0^{\infty} x^a e^{-(b+ ic)x}  dx \,.$$
We employ the substitution $z =(b+ic)x$ and obtain
$$ I = \Re \Biggl[ \frac{1}{(b+i c)^{a+1}} \int_0^\infty z^a e^{-z} \!dz \Biggr] =  \Re \biggl[ \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{(b+i c)^{a+1}} \biggr]\,.$$
For $a,b,c>0$, we can evaluate the real part explicitely and obtain
$$ I = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{(b^2+c^2)^{(a+1)/2}} \cos\Bigl[(a+1) \arctan(c/b) \Bigr] \,.$$
If $a=n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can write it a bit more cleanly
$$ \frac{n!}{(b^2+c^2)^{(n+1)/2}} T_{n+1}\Bigl(b/\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\Bigr) ,$$
where $T_n$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind.

Comment: Nice solution! I think it also matches with the observation I made - If we think of [C,S] as a vector, then the rotation matrix formed seems to rotate the vector by an angle of $\ arctan(\frac{c}{b})$ to give the new vector. Thus, the original vector, which when multiplied by the matrix raised (a+1) times, will get rotated to $\ (a+1) \cdot \ arctan(\frac{c}{b})$.

Comment: Probably ought to explain how the integration with respect to $z$ remains on $(0,\infty)$, rather than a ray in the complex plane.